# Locust greenlets continue to run even after runner quits

Tags: python, locust

I have a use case where I need to produce specific number of messages to Kafka using locust as a library ( reference - https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/use-as-lib.html ). Since locust does not stop after specific number of requests, I am using a counter to cap the number of requests, and quitting the runners once the requests have been handled. Here is the snippet:

```
def handle_request(self):
    if self.current_count == self.total_count:
        raise StopUser
    else:
        # handle request
        self.current_count += 1

def on_stop(self):
    self.environment.runner.quit()
```

Locust version used: 1.4.3

**Issue:**
Even though the user has been stopped and killed, the greenlets spawned in locust continue to run, and the stats-printer continues to print to the console.

- Is there a way I could make locust could stop after specific number of requests?
- Is there a way I could quit the runners from within the locustfile and let the library handler know that the greenlets can now join with greenlet.join()?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```py
from locust.env import Environment

env = Environment(user_classes=[
    UserClass,
    ])
env.create_local_runner()

#optional web ui
env.create_web_ui("127.0.0.1", 8089)

# Configure greenlet events
gevent.spawn(stats_printer(env.stats))
gevent.spawn(stats_history, env.runner)

env.runner.start(USER_COUNT, spawn_rate=SPAWN_RATE)
# ... your other code

def stop_program():
   env.runner.quit()
   env.runner.greenlet.join()
   env.web_ui.stop()

# whenever you want to quit
# stop_program()
```

This creates an environment with some users, spins up a web UI, starts the gevents, and stops the program.